# How can I create a currency convert in this?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I was asked to implement a currency convert as the course assignment showing as below and here is my question:

1. What is the component in red rectangular called? Is it a dropdown? But how is that double arrow format created? I have searched bootstrap dropdowns, but they dont provide such a format (double arrow dropdown) and this assignment probably doesnt allow us to use bootstrap either.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/or5BY.png

Answer (score 0):

You should uses  to get the dropdown. That will only be one arrow on windows. On Mac it will be double arrows. If you want to achieve double arrows you can do something like this.

```css
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
 
.selectdiv {
  position: relative;
  /*Don't really need this just for demo styling*/
  
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin: 50px 33%;
}
 
/*To remove button from IE11, thank you Matt */
select::-ms-expand {
     display: none;
}
 
.selectdiv:after {
  content: '<>';
  font: 17px "Consolas", monospace;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 11px;
  /*Adjust for position however you want*/
  
  top: 18px;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  /*left line */
  
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
 
.selectdiv select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 320px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.75;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -ms-word-break: normal;
  word-break: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectdiv">
  <label>
      <select>
          <option selected> Select Box </option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Last long option</option>
      </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3) is another example how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks so much normal!